# WordPress + php , glob() is not working in cron job function

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, glob

I have a directory which has multiple XML files and I am retrieving all XML files via glob function. It is working when I am using on submit button, but when i use it on cron job then it does not work and it can't be retrieve XML files.

```
$date =  date('d');
$path = "../data/".$date;
define('MY_PLUGIN_DIR',$path);
$files = glob(MY_PLUGIN_DIR."/*.XML", GLOB_BRACE);
print_r($files);
```

can you suggest me what should i do for it ?

Comment: what `submit button` do? how does it works?

Comment: The working directory is most likely different when you execute the script via CLI. Just specify full, absolute paths instead of relative ones.

Comment: I have built it via submit button. but now I want it automatic via cron job

Comment: Thanks ,  absolute paths worked for me